# How to replace space with underscore in a typen text in a form using PHP or javascript in exesting script

Tags: php, replace

I need a little help. I have created the below script. A form that save its info to my database and a long with that it create some (2 on different paths) folders on the server.

My issue is that in the form under ”folder” you can type the name of the folder you want to create along with the info that is saved in the database. At the moment everything works just as it should. My request/issue is how do a replace space “ “ from the folder name to an underscore “_”

Means, if someone enters a folder name called “My Folder Photo” I need the script to change the name to: “my_folder_photo” so it will work in urls on the website.

The is my codes so fare:

```
<?php
include "../config.php";
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
mysql_query("insert into profiles set name= '".$_POST["name"]."', age= '".$_POST["age"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."', folder = '".$_POST["folder"]."'");

$folder = $_POST['folder'];
$path1 = '../game1/photos/' . $folder;
$path2 = '../game2/photos/' . $folder;
mkdir($path1);
mkdir($path2);
header("Location: myprofile-new-step2.php");

exit;
}

?>


<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" name="myform" id="myform">
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  border="0" align="center"><tr><td width="70">
Name: 
</td><td width="270">
<input type="text" name="name" size="40">
</td><td>

</td></tr><tr><td>
Age: 
</td><td>
<input type="text" name="age" size="40">
</td><td>

</td></tr><tr><td>
Country: 
</td><td>
<select name="country"  data-placeholder="<?=$country?>" class="chosen-select" style="width:250px;" id="<?=$country?>" value="<?=$country?>"  <?= (!empty($country) ? 'checked="checked"' : "")?>>
            <option value="<?=$country?>"></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
</td><td>
Enter the country you live in.
</td></tr><tr><td>
Folder: 
</td><td>
<input type="text" name="folder" size="40"  id="folder">
</td><td>

</td></tr></table> 
<center><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="send" title="NEXT" value="NEXT"></center>
</form>
```

Im a new to php so need as much help as possible to figure this out :) THANKS

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
$folder = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($_POST['folder']));
```

See [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/strtolower) for making the folder name lowercase, and [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) for replacing spaces with underscores.

I would also recommend using [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename) to help ensure that someone doesn't try to submit a malicious path.

Comment: I have tried to replace the line: `$folder = $_POST['folder'];` with your line: `$folder = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($_POST['folder']));` and the folders name are created with underscore instead of Space. But in my database its not saved with the "_" there its saved Space. Means I still ned to figure out how to change it in what is saved to the database. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @GernerChristensen Look at your insert query. You are inserting `$_POST["folder"]` into the database, not the modified `$folder`.

Comment: but how do I do that? As I see it first the folder name is saved in the database after that the folder name is changed and the folder is created with an underscore. How do I change the pricess so the underscore name also is saved in the database?

Comment: Uh, just reverse the order. Created the modified folder first. Then do your database query.

Comment: if I change it around then the info is not send to the database. Here is the code I have changed it to: `$folder = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($_POST['folder'])); 
$path1 = '../members/movies/' . $folder;
$path2 = '../members/photos/' . $folder;
mkdir($path1);
mkdir($path2);

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
mysql_query("insert into profiles set stagename= '".$_POST["stagename"]."', stageage= '".$_POST["stageage"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."', folder = '".$_POST["folder"]."'");

header("Location: myprofile-new-step2.php");
exit;`Can you please advice? I have tryed to change it around.

Comment: In your insert query make sure `folder = '$folder'` and not `$_POST['folder']`

Comment: thanks for your update. Im affraid im not sure what you exact want me to change and in what order you want to codes. Can you please show me?

Comment: hehe I found out `mysql_query("insert into profiles set stagename= '".$_POST["stagename"]."', stageage= '".$_POST["stageage"]."', country = '".$_POST["country"]."', folder = '$folder'");` Earlyer you wrote something about `basename()` to make it more secure. How do I add that?  Im so thankfull for your help in this matter THANKS.

Comment: @GernerChristensen Imagine a user submits `../../../../something/malicious` as `$_POST['folder']`. Right now you would just use it, and create a directory someplace you don't really want. Use `basename()` to protect against that: `$folder = basename(str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($_POST['folder'])));`. See http://us2.php.net/basename for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
strtolower(str_replace(" ", '_', $string));
```

Replaces the space with an underscore. `$string` in the name of the folder, in your case.

**[str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)**

Comment: Adi,  Can you write a Little more of The code? There Are missing alot before it Will Work :)